# Using neural networks to solve polynomials

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

Is it possible to train a neural network to solve a polynomial equation? What about any non-linear single variable equation?
Here are possible methods that I am thinking of trying:

1. Training a neural network to model some polynomial $P(x)$ and setting the output to $0$ then maybe devising some sort of algorithm with produces an approximation of the corresponding input.
2. Doing (1) but make a new NN which is the inverse function of the first NN. Then finding the root from inputting $0$ into the second NN.

I thought this might be an interesting science fair topic with many applications and possibilities for future study but I would like to know if it is doable. I will first attempt cubics, then successively higher degree polynomials.

Comment: I can't see how you would make this work. Every polynomial will be associated with the same ouput (namely, the number zero). It doesn't look like you can do supervised learning there.

Comment: I understand that the question is rather "can we solve f(x)=0 by trying to solve g(x)=0, where g represents a neural network fitted to a function f?". Nice idea, but it might be worth starting by checking for some existing papers on the topic.